# Ubuntu will not run elf file

Tags: 18.04, binary

Running Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS and have downloaded an ELF file, but it will not run from the terminal when I type in what I think is the correct command to run. I've verified that it is an ELF file, but still running into a roadblock and cannot move forward.

Any ideas? Or recommendations on how to proceed are greatly appreciated.

Comment: what does "will not run" mean? What are you seeing that makes you think something is wrong? Is there an error message?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the actual command that you attempted to run.

Comment: So I read somewhere that in order to execute and ELF file I have to use the command "sudo chmod +x file.name" will make the file executable and then typing in "./file.name" to

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm going about this the right way, but just trying to find a flag inside this ELF file